# Differences : Single-node and Multi-node

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I'm trying to install Hadoop in a virtual machine, I found a tutorial explaining how to do that in a multi-node cluster .

So my question is what's the difference between a single-node and a multi-node cluster ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you be more specific? From which aspect do you want to know the difference? Configuration settings? Implementation? Performance? Something else?

Comment: @vefthym I think he wants to know what the difference is, not what effects the difference has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Single node cluster** : By default, Hadoop is configured to run in a non-distributed or standalone mode, as a single Java process. There are no daemons running and everything runs in a single JVM instance. HDFS is not used.

**Pseudo-distributed or multi-node cluster**: The Hadoop daemons run on a local machine, thus simulating a cluster on a small scale. Different Hadoop daemons run in different JVM instances, but on a single machine. HDFS is used instead of local FS

Answer (score 0):

And you can have your work environment set up as follow

Step 1 - Download VMware player latest version and install on your laptop/desktop. You can also install VMware tools, which will be very useful for your working with guest OS.

Step 2 - Once you Step 1 is completed then Download Cloudera Quick Start VM from
http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/downloads/download-components/download-products.html?productID=F6mO278Rvo

Step 3 -  Open VMPlayer program and click on “Open a virtual Machine”. and go to directory “cloudera-quickstart-vm-4.4.0-1-vmware”. Select cloudera-quickstart-vm-4.4.0-1-vmware. This will create a virtual machine instance in VM Player.

Step 4 - Start the Cloudera VM by Clicking on power on to start the Cloudera Demo VM.

You are good to go

Good luck